# Calculation about fermions via quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, vacuum, fermions

I want to ask a specific question occurred in my current learning about neutrinos.

What I want to calculate is an amplititude:
\begin{equation}
\langle\Omega|a_{\bf k m}a_{\bf pj}a_{\bf qi}^{\dagger}a_{\bf kn}^{\dagger}|\Omega\rangle
\end{equation}
Here, $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ are the annihillation and generation operator of neutrinos, subscript $\bf k,p,q$ are momentum and $\bf i,j,m$ are the mass eigenstates. $|\Omega\rangle$ is supposed to be the background neutrinos and both the initial state and final state. Applying the number operator to introduce the distribution function:
$$
a^{\dagger}_{\bf p}a_{\bf p}|{\bf p}\rangle=n_p|{\bf p}\rangle,n_{\bf p}=\int\mathrm dx^3f(x,p)
$$
I want to figure out the result expressed by $f$ and some delta function. But I am a little unfamiliar with complex field theory calculations, and I am helpless after doing an exchange of two intermediate operators for this formula. Could you please help me see if this problem can be solved? If so, what is the idea of calculation?